# Hard drives working on Linux but no so much on Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ntfs

there,
I am having this problem:
I have 3 sata hard drives that are working perfectly on Ubuntu but on Windows 7 two of them work awful (very very often it hangs for like 2 minutes to load the contents of a folder) and the other one is not even recognized.
Also, the windows 7 boot is taking ages and i think it's because of this,
I am pretty lost here... any ideas?
The 3 of them are ntfs.
Thanks

Comment: Are the drives fragmented?

Comment: Since Windows is booting slowly I would consider the possibility of checking for malware. I had a similar problem and it turn out I had a rootkit virus.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the filesystems are slightly corrupt (or have been corrupted by Linux) and if it needs an fsck in Windows ? While NTFS is supported under Linux, its not a native filesystem.

Another possibility (but I'd imagine less likely) is something to do with Advanced Formatting/GUID and different ways of reading large drives/backward compatibility ?  If your drives are > 2tb, this is worth serious exploration.